# How to delete bridge permently

Tags: networking, delete, permanent-delete

I use `sudo brctl delbr br0` but its back after reboot. I also tryd `sudo brctl delif br0`. But it always back after rebooting.

`cat /etc/network/interfaces`

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

`cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml`

```
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  ethernets:
    enp4s0f0:
      dhcp4: no
      addresses: [10.0.0.199/24]
      gateway4: 10.0.0.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8, 1.1.1.1]
```

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu? How did you setup the bridge?

Comment: Its 18.04.5. I dont remebr ever setup. Ty

Comment: Is it a server?  Look into `/etc/network/interfaces`

Comment: And also: `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml`

Comment: for a wild shot `dpkg -l | grep bridge-utils`